# Missing jpeglib.h when building pygame in Cygwin

Tags: python-2.7, cygwin, pygame

I'm trying to install pygame with cygwin with the step by step below

http://msdl.cs.mcgill.ca/people/tfeng/svmsccdoc/node49.html

Things are going fine until the last part when I'm running theses 3 lines

```
export LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:$LIBRARY_PATH
export CPATH=/usr/local/include/SDL:$CPATH
python setup.py install build
```

I have this issue

```
gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -ggdb -O2 -pipe -Wimplicit-function-declaration -    fdebug-prefix-map=/usr/src/ports/python/python-2.7.8-1.i686/build=/usr/src/debug/python-2.7.8-1 -fdebug-prefix-map=/usr/src/ports/python/python-2.7.8-1.i686/src/Python-2.7.8=/usr/src/debug/python-2.7.8-1 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/NEED_INC_PATH_FIX -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/imageext.c -o build/temp.cygwin-1.7.33-i686-2.7/src/imageext.o
src/imageext.c:35:21: erreur fatale: jpeglib.h : No such file or directory
#include <jpeglib.h>
```

As you can see, the file `jpeglib.h` is missing

I tried to install the missing file by downloading the lib

```
apt-cyg install libjpeg62
```

But to no avail

Does anyone have seen that issue before? I browsed the net but found nothing relevant.

TIA

Comment: You can improve this question by specifying what you mean when you say 'But to no avail'.  That only means it didn't work for you, but there's indication for why that is so, whether because it didn't install properly or if it installed but didn't help, or whatever.  In this case it didn't matter, but it's still unclear and unhelpful.

Comment: I've installed the libjpeg62 but I still have a missing `<jpeglib.h>`file.

Comment: Let me do the whole step by step again. Grinding my teeth on cygwin. grhhh

Comment: You don't need `libjpeg62`, you need `libjpeg-devel` as I answered below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`libjpeg62` doesn't have `jpeglib.h`.  You need `libjpeg-devel` instead.

You can search for specific files in packages using the [package search function](http://cygwin.com/packages/) on the Cygwin website.

Answer (score 0):

You can download an already compiled version of PyGame and skip these steps. This can be painful sometimes.

Just check this page : http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

or

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame , to get directly to PyGame section.

The Python extension unofficial windows binaries. You can find alot of Python libraries on this page.

Using theses packages will make you save a lot of time.

Comment: Hi Jordsti, thanks but I'm keen of using cygwin and it is not doing well with Cygwin. The first page is saying that the packages are not good with cygwin ...